# Azure DevOps 2019 - Dashboard chart doesn't drill down

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I have created pie chart widget/report to show status of Workshops (custom field) in Azure DevOps 2019:

[image: Pie Chart]

When I click on Business review (2, Green color) it should show only 2 records in drill down report (or) Query from same pie chart widget. But it is showing all 6 records as shown:

[image: Query_Output_When_Business Review(2)_Clicked]

Is it possible to achieve this drill-down functionality in Azure DevOps 2019?

If I modify query it will only show 2 records in Pie chart, which is not I want. I want Pie chart to remain as is & if I click on particular status it should particular records in output/Query like in MS Excel Pivot/reports.

Same way for other ADO 2019 widgets, if I click on particular status/record it should show only that particular record(s) instead of all which is not happening in Azure DevOps 2019 reports/widgets.

Answer (score 1):

That's just the behavior of the charts unfortunately.  As far as I know there is no way to configure that and there doesn't appear to be any new community widgets that would cover this.  There is a developer community's [feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/526855/clicking-a-graph-or-chart-section-should-display-s-1.html) that has been open a while.  You can upvote it there.

The way I've handled this is just have a row or column of counter tiles that sits along-side the chart widget.  If you want to drill down, you'd use one of the counter widgets.